# Laravel 5.2 Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on a project with Laravel 5.2 and was making a simple form, but I get the error:

Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\codehacking\resources\views\admin\posts\create.blade.php)

and this is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.admin')



@section('content')

    <h1>Create Post</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminPostsController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}


        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
          {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
          {!! Form::select('category_id', array(''=> 'options'), null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('photo_id', 'Photo:') !!}
          {!! Form::file('photo_id', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('body', 'Description:') !!}
          {!! Form::textarea('body', ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::submit('Create Post', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
        </div>   

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

@stop

I thought the error might be with the select element, since in that element I am creating an array with options, but I was getting the same error even when I removed the element.
Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the line in the complete error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is on textarea

```
  {!! Form::textarea('body', null,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```